# how to add particular item by comparing one list with another and add item in list

Tags: c#, list

```
private List<ProjectEmployee> ProjectEmployeeList { get; set; } = new List<ProjectEmployee>(); 
                                                                   //List for Add employee to project
     public string ProjectEmployeeId { get; set; }
     public string EmployeeProjectid { get; set; } 

     public List<ProjectEmployee> projectemployeelist
        {
            get { return ProjectEmployeeList; }
        }


 public void AddEmployeeToProject(ProjectEmployee projectemployee) // to add employee to project
    {
        ProjectBusinessLogic projectbusinessList = new ProjectBusinessLogic();// object to 
                                                                      access project list

        EmployeeBusinessLogic employeebusinessList = new EmployeeBusinessLogic();//object to 
                                                                      access employeelist

        if(projectbusinessList.projectlist.Any(x=>x.ProjectId == projectemployee.ProjectEmployeeId) ||
            employeebusinessList.employeelist.Any(y => y.EmployeeId==projectemployee.EmployeeProjectid))
        {            
            ProjectEmployeeList.Add(projectemployee);
        }
    }
```

In this method I am comparing two list data that is why used object projectbusinessList  and
object employeebusinessList

with this method I am not able to add the things into ProjectEmployee List.. can anyone tell me what to do??

so my requirment is "projectid" must be already there in "projectlist" and "employeeid" also in "employeelist" .....

then the value of "projectid" from project list will be compare with "projectemployeeid" if its there then it will add into "projectemployee list" and same for employeeprojectid also....

so if both this conditions are true then it will add into projectemployeelist

Comment: Are you looking for the [Enumerable.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: Deja vu.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70576545/how-to-compare-two-list-from-two-different-classes-and-compare-particular-condit and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70554186/how-to-remove-particular-item-from-list-in-c

Answer (score 0):

> so my requirment is "projectid" must be already there in "projectlist" ***and*** "employeeid" also in "employeelist" .....

So if you know it is **and**, why does the logic say OR (`||`):

```
if(projectbusinessList.projectlist.Any(x=>x.ProjectId == projectemployee.ProjectEmployeeId) ||
        employeebusinessList.employeelist.Any(y => y.EmployeeId==projectemployee.EmployeeProjectid))
```

Right now it adds if the employeeid is in either project, or employee or both... But you only want the both part.. That's "and", which is `&&`

---

Also, i think the names you're choosing for things aren't doing you any favors; they're very hard to follow: a `projectemployee` has a `EmployeeProjectid` and a `ProjectEmployeeId` - if `projectemployee` is defining some project:employee mapping, it would be clearer to just have property names like `ProjectId` and `EmployeeId` then you can say "this object maps an employee to a project - that proeprty there is the project id, and this one here is the employee. The fact that they operate in a pair to define a mapping is clear from a) the name of the class and b) the fact that they are both members of the class so there is one A for one B. Each property's name doesn't need to contain the other identifier also. WHat's even more bizarre (for me at least) is that I would assume `ProjectEmployeeId` is "the employeeid in the project" but your `x.ProjectId == projectemployee.ProjectEmployeeId` implies the opposite (and same for the other property)

A recurrent theme on your recent questions is that there are very basic logical errors being made, like there isn't enough planning going into the algorithms - code is being written without thinking "what do I ened this code to do; I'll sketch it out in comments first" - I'd recommend to start out first writing comments in the language you think in, and then translate to c#

Comment: by using "&&" still its not working @Caius Jard